# Tensorflow Object Detection API - Retrain to use Images from different colorspace?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, tensorflow, object-detection

I have been able to retrain Object Detection models to work with my custom classes. But what I want to do now is to modify the input during inference to a different color space (preferably YUV).

Will I need to modify the network ? Can it be done using the same API? Will I still be able to use Transfer Learning or would  I have to train from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably easiest to just convert to RGB, but it is definitely possible to train using transfer learning.  You will still have to save the YUV values as the RGB channels of a JPEG, and it is unclear if there is any significant advantage to doing this instead of simply converting to RGB.

One possible small speed advantage would be if you wanted to represented the chroma (U,V) channels at a reduced spatial resolution (as is commonly done), but this would probably involve designing a custom architecture that could take advantage of this.

Comment: I'm trying to use the model in an Android environment where the default color space of images obtained is in YUV. I want to eliminate the preprocessing steps with time & performance in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You don;t need to change the network architecture.

You could use the same API to train.

But i think you will have a problem with the transfer learning.

The trained network that you are using to do the transfer learning was trained on RGB channels. This means that probably in the first layer you have filters that are looking for specific differences between RGB values. For example finding an edge when you have some difference between the B channel and R channel. This filter will not find the same things for the difference between V and the Y channels.

Because right from the first layer you will have different results this will propagate thorough all the network.

As a general rule if you insert different data to a network than what it expects don't count on getting the same results.

Comment: Do you feel it's impossible or that it's experimental and hence cannot predict the results?

Comment: I think that you will not get the expected results. But i think you can try anyway.